Error E-11 Ink pad change on Epson XP-325

E-11 error or ink pad must be replaced.  The used stamp pad must be
replaced and the associated software counter initialized.

It may be possible to blot the ink pad with cotton buds, but to do
this, you have to push the carriage to the left. When I try to push it
manually, with the printer switched off, I feel a mechanical stop.
Do you have any idea how to push the carriage? Also, how can I get the
printer's counter initialization software?

No, what you suggest in the second paragraph is a waste of time. Whatever you do - cleaning with cotton buds isn't an option, finding a pad from a 3rd party supplier and replacing by DISASSEMBLING the whole thing might be - you can't reset the software counter without a software that isn't available  to end users. You may find several links, free or payed, but most will be either scam, malware/virus or both.
Detailed information at this Spanish ink online store (no endorsement)

For each Epson printer, there are differing instructions for resetting the ink waste pad error.
For the XP-235, Epson offers the following:

A one-time Maintenance Reset Utility, enabling printing for a limited time.
[N.B.: Some third parties sell that tool, without explaining that it is not a permanent fix.]

Customers can contact the Epson Service & Support team at 562-276-1300 (U.S.) or 905-709-9475 (Canada) (https://epson.com/contact-us) about Epson’s low-cost ink pad replacement service...

Customers can also work with a local certified technician to replace the ink pad...

For customers who determine that the printer no longer meets their needs, Epson offers a recycling program as well a wide range of innovative new printing solutions.


This is known as planned obsolescence. Epson is not alone in this practice; for example, I discarded a Brother printer for which the waste ink pad code did not reset the counter.
BTW, HP has bricked printers with non-approved ink. See Cory Doctorow's Unauthorized Bread.
